# CSS element not responsive

Tags: html, css, django-templates

So in my code, other elements of the container are being responsive and working exactly the way I want them to when the device is shrunk, but the `maps` element is not being responsive properly. Now the `maps` element is getting too shrunk and not the same amount as the other elements. Stuck on this for the last 3 days. Any ways to get it to work properly?

[image: normal]

[image: shrunk]

My html file:

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
    <div>
        <iframe src="{{ object.location }}" 
        class="col-lg-12" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your template code is no use to us. To help you debug this we need to be able to reproduce the problem. Please edit your question to include a stack snippet which demonstrates the problem, or at least include all relevant parts of the final code which is sent to the browser.

Comment: [This](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/google-maps/) may be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can add `width="100%"` in your iframe:

OR

2. I made an example here if you like it then use it:

   ```css
   .map-container {
             position: relative;
             overflow: hidden;
             width: 100%;
             padding-top: 75%; /* Adjust this value as needed to maintain the aspect ratio */
         }
     
         .map-container iframe {
             position: absolute;
             top: 0;
             left: 0;
             width: 100%;
             height: 100%;
             border: 0;
         }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="section">
       <div class="container">
       <div class="row justify-content-between">
       <div>
         <div class="map-container">
           <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d235013.74843228213!2d72.414930809941!3d23.020474099659204!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x395e848aba5bd449%3A0x4fcedd11614f6516!2sAhmedabad%2C%20Gujarat!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1703309487976!5m2!1sen!2sin" 
           class="col-lg-12 img-fluid" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
         </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```